# How to delete a record if the next record in table as the same value in specific field

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table with repeated values in the cell_id (integer) field.
I want to delete records where the "n + 1" record has the same value as "n"

This way I will not have repeated values in records that are adjacent/contiguous.

Before

```
id | user_id | cell_id
25 | 5973    | 6051
26 | 5973    | 6051
27 | 5973    | 6051
28 | 5973    | 100
29 | 5973    | 256
30 | 5973    | 256
31 | 5973    | 6051
32 | 5973    | 6051
```

After

```
id | user_id | cell_id
25 | 5973    | 6051
28 | 5973    | 100
29 | 5973    | 256
31 | 5973    | 6051
```

Comment: Many thanks for everyone that give possible solutions to my problem. The solution from Gordon Linoff worked !! many thanks Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use a `join`, which is expressed in a `delete` via `using`:

```
delete from t
    using t t2
    where t2.cell_id = t.cell_id and t2.user_id = t.user_id and
          t2.id = t.id + 1;
```

Comment: Many thanks for everyone that give possible solutions to my problem. The solution from Gordon Linoff worked !! many thanks Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS to check if a row should be deleted:

```
delete from tablename t
where 
  exists (
  select 1 from tablename 
  where cell_id = t.cell_id and user_id = t.user_id and id < t.id
  )
  and
  t.cell_id = (select cell_id from tablename where id = 
  (select max(id) from tablename where id < t.id));
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=ef8a261e39120e2eaed298ff349008f8).
Results:

```
> id | user_id | cell_id
> -: | ------: | ------:
> 25 |    5973 |    6051
> 28 |    5973 |     100
> 29 |    5973 |     256
> 31 |    5973 |    6051
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM
    object a
        USING object b
WHERE
    a.id < b.id
    AND a.cell_id = b.cell_id;
```

Where you would replace 'object' with the name of your table.